# Unable to find route name if added to prefix in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

The below route works fine.

```
Route::get('/create','HolidaysController@create')->name('createHoliday');
```

However, it I get the

> Route [createHoliday] not defined

error when I place it in a route prefix.

```
Route::prefix('holidays')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/create','HolidaysController@create')->name('createHoliday');
});
```

I have cleared all config, cache, route and views through the artisan command without any luck.
Cant figure out why it's not working.
using Laravel 7.24

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` print in both cases?

Comment: how do you use this route? please paste the line you encounter with this error

Answer (score 0):

When we use prefix in routes , the prefix also added in the route name

Please try

```
  holidays.createHoliday
```